# How to export from DataTable to Excel file in text format (even if there are numbers)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am using the following procedure to create an Excel spreadsheet from a DataTable:

```
    protected void UploadDataTableToExcel(DataTable dtEmp, string filename)
    {
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + filename;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        string tab = string.Empty;
        foreach (DataColumn dtcol in dtEmp.Columns)
        {
            Response.Write(tab + dtcol.ColumnName);
            tab = "\t";
        }
        Response.Write("\n");
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtEmp.Rows)
        {
            tab = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < dtEmp.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                Response.Write(tab + Convert.ToString(dr[j]));
                tab = "\t";
            }
            Response.Write("\n");
        }
        Response.End();
    }
```

It works fine except when the cell only has numbers. For example:

- This "6969062201223401504" becomes "6.96902E+18"
- This "076854957" becomes "76854957"

I would like the Excel spreadsheet to preserve every column as text, instead of converting them into integers

Comment: I think the issue here is on the Excel end rather than the C# end...

Comment: @m1Lb4nKs I agree... but there may be a way to tell excel which cell format to use

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/318420/formatting-a-comma-delimited-csv-to-force-excel-to-interpret-value-as-a-string

Comment: Rather than sending Excel `"0123"`, you can send it `"=""0123"""`, and then Excel will display `0123` in the cell, although the actual data stored in the cell will be `="0123"`.

Comment: @m1Lb4nKs just tried that but it didn't work... any other idea would be appreciated